# helper method for know is json row exist in database or no?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I save my json in database with onClick in adapter.
for getting is row of json exist in the database or no I need helper method for that . This is my method but , It isn't work .

> i write this method in QuestionDatabaseAdapter

```
public Boolean isQuestionFavorite(String rawQuestionid) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = null;
        Cursor c = null;

        try {
            c = database.rawQuery("SELECT question_id FROM tbl_questions WHERE question_id = ' " + rawQuestionid + " ' ", null);
            Log.i("CURSOR VALUE ",c.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
                database.close();
            }
        }

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

> And I check if row exist in databse do these works . (In Recycler
>   OnBindViewHolder)

```
 ///========================== FAVORITE CHECKING ========================

        boolean isFavorite = questionDatabaseAdapter.isQuestionFavorite(questionha.get(position).getQuestionId());

        if(isFavorite){
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
        }else {
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
        }
```

But i get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

`database.rawQuery()` can return `null`, so prior to calling `c.moveToFirst()` you should check whether `c != null`.

Comment: is this right my solution for this work (my mean helper method and checking in adapter) , and i say i should return statement , but my returns in the inner method .

Comment: and it say i should return statement , but my returns in the inner method

Comment: do you know what should to do for this probelm ?

Comment: I didn't get what the problem is, who says you should return statement?

Comment: Well yes, your code doesn't return anything if c is null, so return something that you think is meaningful in that case.

Comment: My function is boolean and i want if cursor move to next it return true and false . but my problem they are in inner method

Comment: Your cursor will be null if the query will return no results, which means question with given id is not present in the DB. What would that mean in your case semantically? If it means that it's not favorite - return false, if it's an error - throw an exception.

Comment: i debug my code and i get this exception raised when raw query excecute :                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference